# Extract patches from 3D Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a 3D matrix `A` of dimensions `h x w x c`. I want to extract patches of dimensions `ph x pw` from each "channel" `c`. `ph` divides `h` and `pw` divides `w`. In this example,

```
h x w x c = 4 x 4 x 3
ph x pw = 2 x 2
```

[image: Example]

I know how to do this in tensorflow using `gather_nd` but I was hoping for something more efficient in terms of setting it up, because the dimensions will be big and I'd rather not have the indices array of `gather_nd` in memory. Is there possibly an intelligent reshape? Either numpy or tensorflow solution would be very nice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use some reshaping and swapping of axes -

```
A.reshape(h//ph,ph,w//pw,pw,-1).swapaxes(1,2)
```

Sample run -

```
In [46]: # Sample inputs
    ...: h,w,c = 10,12,3
    ...: ph, pw = 2,2
    ...: A = np.random.randint(0,9,(h,w,c))
    ...: 

In [47]: A.reshape(h//ph,ph,w//pw,pw,-1).swapaxes(1,2).shape
Out[47]: (5, 6, 2, 2, 3)
```

Each element (as block) along first two axes represent the patches. Thus. for the sample provided, we would have `5 x 6 = 30` patches.

If you want those patches along one merged first axis, use one more `reshape` -

```
In [85]: out = A.reshape(h//ph,ph,w//pw,pw,-1).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(-1,ph,pw,c)

In [86]: out.shape
Out[86]: (30, 2, 2, 3)
```

Let's verify by manually inspecting values themselves -

```
In [81]: A[:ph,:pw] # First patch
Out[81]: 
array([[[6, 5, 2],
        [4, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 4],
        [2, 3, 0]]])

In [82]: A[:ph,pw:2*pw] # Second patch
Out[82]: 
array([[[8, 3, 3],
        [0, 0, 2]],

       [[8, 5, 4],
        [3, 4, 6]]])

In [83]: out[0]
Out[83]: 
array([[[6, 5, 2],
        [4, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 4],
        [2, 3, 0]]])

In [84]: out[1]
Out[84]: 
array([[[8, 3, 3],
        [0, 0, 2]],

       [[8, 5, 4],
        [3, 4, 6]]])
```

Comment: very sweet! I understand what's going on but I would never have found the specific `reshape` call you use. Any tips on how to find these myself in the future?

Comment: @fabian789 [`These amazing tools`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html) should be good guide for you! :)